# webview android doesn't store session/cookies

Tags: javascript, java, android-studio, webview

I got an issue. When i set `view.loadUrl("http://mysite");` and trying to login, app doesn't handle the session, and shows that I'm not logged in, but when I'm setting up `view.loadUrl("http://google.com");` and loading my site via google search, the session is establishing correct, other site logins `view.loadUrl("http://othersite")` logging fine too;

Please help, I tried anything but nothing helps... Thank you.

P.S site works well in other browsers.
my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.widget.FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com    /apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.gtr.rox.MainActivity"
android:background="#333333"
android:id="@+id/webview_frame">
<WebView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </android.widget.FrameLayout>
```

Main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView mWebviewPop;
private WebView view;
private FrameLayout mContainer;
private Context mContext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
    view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    mContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.webview_frame);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; ZTE T221 Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.85 Mobile Safari/537.36");
    view.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    view.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    view.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    view.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    view.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    view.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    view.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    view.invalidate();
    view.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser() {
    });
    view.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    view.loadUrl("http://mysite");
    view.setWebChromeClient(new UriChromeClient() {
    });
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    if (!prefs.getBoolean("firstTime", false)) {
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
        manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("firstTime", true);
        editor.apply();
    }
    mContext=this.getApplicationContext();
}


private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.startsWith("tel:") || url.startsWith("sms:") || url.startsWith("smsto:") || url.startsWith("mailto:") || url.startsWith("mms:") || url.startsWith("mmsto:") || url.startsWith("market:") || url.startsWith("https://youtu")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        } else {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler,
                                   SslError error) {
        Log.d("onReceivedSslError", "onReceivedSslError");
        //super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
    }

}
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && view.canGoBack()) {
        view.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
class UriChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog,
                                  boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
        mWebviewPop = new WebView(mContext);
        mWebviewPop.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebviewPop.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        mWebviewPop.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        mWebviewPop.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebviewPop.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
        mWebviewPop.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        mWebviewPop.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebviewPop.getSettings().setSavePassword(true);
        mWebviewPop.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        mWebviewPop.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        mWebviewPop.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        mWebviewPop.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        mWebviewPop.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mWebviewPop.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        mContainer.addView(mWebviewPop);
        WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
        transport.setWebView(mWebviewPop);
        resultMsg.sendToTarget();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCloseWindow(WebView window) {
        Log.d("onCloseWindow", "called");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Solved by remove this line

```
 view.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
```

And it works!